# Reading the last batch of data added to hdfs file using Python

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have a program that will add a variable number of rows of data to an hdf5 file as shown below.

```
data_without_cosmic.to_hdf(new_file,key='s', append=True, mode='r+', format='table')
```

`New_file` is the file name and `data_without_cosmic` is a pandas data frame with 'x' , 'y', 'z', and  'i' columns representing positional data and a scalar quantity. I may add several data frames of this form to the file each time I run the full program. For each data frame I add, the 'z' values are a constant value.

The next time I use the program, I would need to access the last batch of rows that was added to the data in order to perform some operations. I wondered if there was a fast way to retrieve just the last data frame that was added to the file or if I could group the data in some way as I add it in order to be able to do so.

The only other way I can think of achieving my goal is by reading the entire file and then checking the z values from bottom up until it changes, but that seemed a little excessive. Any ideas?

P.S I am very inexperienced with working with hdf5 files but I read that they are efficient to work with.